# Build project with EJB dependencies with Ant on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, ejb

I want to build a web project (war) with Apache Ant. The project has dependencies to classes in `javax.ejb` and similar packages which are included in my server runtime. So building with eclipse works fine. However, when trying to build the war with Apache Ant, the following error occurs:

```
[javac] ...\Test.java:3: error: package javax.ejb does not exist
[javac] import javax.ejb.Timeout;
[javac]                 ^
[javac] ...\Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     @Timeout
[javac]      ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Timeout
[javac]   location: class Test
[javac] 2 errors
```

You can reproduce the problem with the following minimal example.

Test.java

```
import javax.ejb.Timeout;

public class Test {
    @Timeout
    public void test() {}
}
```

build.xml

```
<project name="Test" default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I know this can be solved by adding the server runtime to the classpath, but since I want to build the project on a Jenkins server where no server runtime exists, I was wondering if there is any possibility to build this project without the runtime.